# Pins on a map like UI

Tags: c#, xaml, maps, uwp, scrollviewer

Sorry if the title isn't very clear, but I didn't know how to describe exactly what I'm looking for.

So what I've got is a very large image in a scrollviewer:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollView" ZoomMode="Enabled" HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" MinZoomFactor="1" ViewChanged="scrollView_ViewChanged">
    <Grid Width="{Binding Path=ViewportWidth, ElementName=scrollView}">
        <Image x:Name="img" Source="The Known World.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

And I want to place pin like UI elements that will stick to a location on a map, but will not scale along with the scrollviewer. Like the name of towns on Google Maps. I've tried various things, such as having:

```
<Scrollviewer>
    <Grid Width="{Binding Path=ScrollableWidth, ElementName=scrollView}"
          Height="{Binding Path=ScrollableHeight, ElementName=scrollView}">
          <!--Pins here-->
    </Grid>
<Scrollviewer>
```

But nothing that behaves as expected. What can I do to get this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting :)

My idea is ... put a pin layer over the scroll viewer.

```
<Grid>
  <ScrollViewer x:name="imageSv" >
  </ScrollViewer>
  <Canvas x:name="pinCanvas" />
</Grid>
```

You may know the "image-based" xy position of the pin. And, when the user scroll or zoom in/out the scroll viewer, you can get the xy offset and zoom ratio. Then, you can calculate the overlayed xy position of the pin, and draw it on pinCanvas.

Advantage of this idea is - you can avoid the pin scaling process.

Answer (score 1):

It's a really interesting and tricky question at the same time.
I would approach it with a Canvas which I can use to properly place my pins on top of the image and ensure that their locations will remain fixed regardless of the scroll viewer position.

The tricky part comes when you say you want the pins to *not* scale with the scroll viewer. The only idea I have there is you can try to track the zoom scale on the scroll viewer, and apply an inverse of that to the pins (so if at scroll Viewer ZoomScale of 1, you have a scale of 1 on your pins, at ZoomScale = 2, you have PinScale = 1/2)

Not sure that would work, but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution I found, inspired by Alex Drenea's answer:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollView" ZoomMode="Enabled" HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" MinZoomFactor="1" ViewChanged="scrollView_ViewChanged" ViewChanging="scrollView_ViewChanging" Visibility="Visible">
    <Viewbox x:Name="vb" Height="{Binding Path=ViewportHeight, ElementName=scrollView}">
        <Grid>
            <Image x:Name="img" Stretch="UniformToFill" Source="The Known World.jpg"/>
            <local:PinPoint Text="Hardhome" MinZoom="0.9" Size="{Binding ElementName=scrollView, Path=ExtentHeight, Converter={StaticResource conv},ConverterParameter=scrollView}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="2825,261,0,0"/>
        </Grid>
    </Viewbox>
</ScrollViewer>
```

MinZoom is a property on my custom UserControl that controls the ScaleTransform.

And this is the converter:

```
public class ViewBoxConstantFontSizeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {

        return 100 / (double)value * 20;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```